# Rapidly testing for exact vs. inexact expressions

Tags: expression-test

Is there a fast function "`ExactExpressionQ`" to test whether an expression is exact vs inexact? I'm looking for something like `ExactNumberQ` that works for expressions.

My attempt at this is

```
ExactExpressionQ[expr_] := FreeQ[expr, _Real|_Complex?InexactNumberQ]

ExactExpressionQ[0]
ExactExpressionQ[0.]
ExactExpressionQ[(2.1 + I) x]
ExactExpressionQ[Sin[x]]

(* True *)
(* False *)
(* False *)
(* True *)
```

Is there something better?

Comment: Is it OK that e.g. `Floor[1.4*x]` is treated as inexact? I think `Floor` always produces exact integers if given numbers, whether exact or inexact.

Comment: That's a good point; one would have to think about certain functions returning exact results even if their input may be inexact.  For the case at hand, let's just ask that `ExactExpressionQ` tests whether the input expression is literally exact or not.

Comment: One issue is that `Complex` can head an exact number. Have to peek inside...

Comment: You can shorten your definition to `ExactExpressionQ[expr_] := FreeQ[expr, _?InexactNumberQ]`

Comment: @BobHanlon That's a good point.  Do you think it might be slower, though?  It has to PatternTest every piece of `expr`, whereas what I have PatternTests only if there is something with head `Complex`.

Comment: @BobHanlon I just tried both versions out with a few really long expressions I have which pass as `True` (worst case), and I'm finding what I have so far is between 2 and 8 times faster.

Comment: It seems giving *levelspec* `-1` would help and still give the desired result.  (Can't test here though).

Comment: @george2079 Yep, giving *levelspec* `{-1}` improves speed by factor 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using george2079's suggestion, the code can be tweaked to

```
ExactExpressionQ[expr_] := FreeQ[expr, _Real|_Complex?InexactNumberQ, {-1}]
```

for better performance.